# why TFIDF is not giving correct output?

Tags: text-classification, tf-idf, multilabel-classification, tfidfvectorizer, dictvectorizer

I am trying to  apply TFIDF on this chunk of data .(this actually is part of my dataset but i am not getting correct ans)
[here is the code snipt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkorL.png)
[here is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SF3e4.png)

here you can see most values are zero.
when i applied only one sentence it gves the values but when i increased it is giving sparse(same is happening when i applied it to whole dataset

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We have rules about what sort of questions can be asked here. Several of your questions appear to not follow those rules. Please take the [tour] to learn about this site and also read the [help] pages to learn the rules.